# What's the difference between「どこかで犯人を見ましたか」and「犯人をどこかで見ましたか」?

Tags: syntax, word-order

I saw in a book the following sentence used in an example:

> 犯人をどこかで見ましたか

Shouldn't it be「どこかで犯人を見ましたか」?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/59876/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19433/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48808/9831

Answer (score 2):

I feel there is no difference. You would hear both in natural Japanese conversation.